# How to Read & Write to Guest Root directory from Host. (MAC host) (Centos guest) using Vagrant & Virtual Box

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox, directory, shared

Running Vagrant( Virtualbox & centos 6.7) on  Mac OS X (host os).

Using Mac OS X as host OS, having vagrant after setting up a Centos 6.7 Virtual Box Os.

I want to be able to r&w the entire file system of Centos from Mac osx.

I want to do a file system diff between two centos vm's using MAC.

How do i do set this up ?

Comment: you can [check here](http://superuser.com/questions/241825/share-virtualbox-folders-in-reverse-guest-host)

Comment: Ok thanks very much.

Comment: this worked. Thanks